# Importing raster and vector: GRASS GIS 6.4.4

Tags: grass-gis

Almost giving up on this task, and need some support. I´ve been studying GRASS GIS and training with some tutorials with The NC-dataset. What I want is doing the same task as the one called "Surface and volume calculation" from Open Source GIS - A Grass GIS Approach (3. edition).

My problem is that neither raster or vector formats can be imported. The files are there, but the "import-button" are still greyed out. I´ve got a bigger DTM-file wich i clip within QGIS, plus I need to rasterize my vectorlayer for mask when preparing for r.volume excavation.

What works is the original DTM-file. By that I  mean that it can be imported (consists of an .asc and .tab for mapinfo)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using QGIS (especially a recent version), you don't have to import your data into GRASS.  Just load it as a layer in QGIS and then use the GRASS functions from the Processing Toolbox (FKA Sextante).  This way you can sidestep GRASS' quirky project setup process and just get on with using its great tools.

Comment: I suggest you to got with GRASS without using QGIS. Create a Location (and a mapset) for your data and import them inside it.

Comment: Yes I know that it's capable to use from within QGIS. I use it as standalone because nviz-viewer doesn't work in my QGIS. I did all the settings with location and so on. The problem seems to root from QGIS itself. When making new vectorlayers or clipping rasters the problem occurs. If I open layers that hasn't been edited in QGIS everything is fine. What I found out is, if I import and convert the layers into Mapinfo as .tab. they'll afterwards work fine. I've experienced a similar problem like this before, when handling layers in QGIS latest versions. Maybe I need a new fresh install.